Using Find Command to list all the files in the order of their creation/arrival
We are working on a recursive logic to find all the files with a pattern and then pick up only one file at a time that has arrived earlier and then pick up the next file from the list to process.
The requirement is to create a filelist based on the file creation/arrival on the unix system but below comment is listing the files based on their naming convention it seems..
Please assist if we can list down the files names based on their creation OR arrival or the timestamp in the file name in the order and then pick up the file accordingly through recursion..
Command we are using:
find . -type f -name "FILE_NAME*.CSV"

but it's not working as expected. Please advise.

You say something about a timestamp in the name but do not show any examples.  The find utility does not sort names, so that may not be the best approach. Personally, I would probably go for using zsh, but it's unclear what the filenames look like.

Few file systems support the immutable "Birth" timestamp. The other three timestamps cannot be relied on to have the arrival or creation date. For example, if the file arrived in a tar archive, the dates will be preserved from the original machine (so the modified date may be earlier than the creation date). Any of the times can be modified by the touch command.

Similar: sort directories by last modified content (recursive)

find in itself doesn't really sort. But GNU find can print the timestamp along the filename with -printf and then you can sort with sort. E.g. like so:
$ find doc  -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" |sort -n | head
783376319.0000000000 doc/article.txt
919286022.0000000000 doc/INTRO
919286124.0000000000 doc/README
938460221.0000000000 doc/rose94.ps
939135511.0000000000 doc/htmlpost.sh
1054224216.0000000000 doc/infopost.sh
1135958198.0000000000 doc/rose94.pdf
1218547491.0000000000 doc/rbash.1

That's the mtime in seconds past the epoch, with nanoseconds.
However, note that none of the three common timestamps match file "creation", as atime (possiblye) changes on any access, mtime changes on any write, and ctime changes on any inode modification (including writes). %T as above uses mtime, which might or might not work for you.
(Also, using line-based output like that will break if any of the filenames contain newlines, don't do that.)
Anyway, I would avoid trying to sort files in order to find new ones, and rather create new files in a separate directory, and then move them to the final location after processing. That way, you'll know anything in the staging directory is new and needs to be processed, and anything not in there has already been processed.

With zsh,
files=( **/FILE_NAME*.CSV(ND.Om) )

Would build a list of regular files whose name matches that pattern found in the current working directory or below, Ordered by last modification time (the creation time of the contents of the file¹) from oldest to newest.
Then you can loop over them with:
for file ($files) something with $file


¹ Many systems also record a birth time (in filesystems that support it which tends to be the norm these days), but the API to retrieve those if any is not portable (and on Linux-based systems at least, relatively recent), and zsh doesn't have an option to sort files based on that. That timestamp is also often less useful than the modification time as files are never created whole in one go and can have been created long before they're made available at a given path (under a given name) and possibly with an entirely different content.
